# Can't access elements of an array built from readarray

Tags: bash, array, bash-array

I'm trying to build a basic REPL in bash.
The script dynamically populates a list of files in a directory for the user to run.

File space:

```
|
|\ scripts/
|| script1.sh
|| script2.sh
|
\  shell/
 | shell.bashrc
 | shell.desktop
```

From shell.bashrc, I'm using the following command to get an array of filenames:

```
readarray -d " " filenames < <(find ../bin -type f -executable)
```

I can print the array `filenames` just fine and it contains a space separated string that holds `"script1.sh script2.sh"` as expected.

But when I try to access the first element of the array with `echo ${filenames[0]}` it prints every element. Any other index besides 0 returns an empty string.

My bash version is 5.0.17, and the first line of the file is `#!/bin/bash`

I moved to using "readarray" after trying the following led to similar results:

```
filenames=($(find "../bin" -type f -executable))
```

Edit: Found a dumb workaround and would still like to know where the original post is messing up.
Workaround:

```
readarray -d " " filenames < <(find ../bin -type f -executable)
arr=($filenames)
echo ${arr[1]}
```

Which prints the 6th element of the array as expected.

Comment: Related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `find` outputs results separated by newlines. By setting `-d " "` in the mapfile/readarray command, you are causing (assuming none of the names *contains* a space character) all of the results to be concatenated into a single string - newlines and all. When you then `echo ${filenames[0]}` (with *unquoted* variable expansion `${filenames[0]}` and the default space-tab-newline value of `IFS`), the shell splits on newline, and `echo` reassembles the result using spaces<sup>1</sup>.

Instead use

```
readarray -t filenames < <(find ../bin -type f -executable)
```

which will parse the input as newline separated data, but strip the trailing newlines from the stored elements. Or - better - if your bash version supports it,

```
readarray -t -d '' filenames < <(find ../bin -type f -executable -print0)
```

which uses null bytes instead of newlines (making it safe for all legal filenames, even those that contain newlines).

---

<sup>1</sup> See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: Using variables without double-quotes (e.g. `echo ${filenames[0]}` instead of `echo "${filenames[0]}"`) is almost always a mistake (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)). Especially for arrays, `declare -p filename` is often even more helpful at figuring out what's actually stored in a variable.

Comment: Thank you! Both solutions worked like a charm. I'm glad that the solution was a bit more than a syntax error haha. The reason my workaround worked then is because in the reassembling of filenames[0], it was a space separated string as expected for the indexing, right?

Comment: @user3116064 almost - it's really because `$filenames` is equivalent to `${filenames[0]}` and the `(...)` array constructor uses the same space-tab-newline `IFS` value, so it doesn't matter which particular whitespace character is the delimiter.